# Is it possible to display a view inside a tile's content?

Tags: sapui5

I have a home page where there are tiles which will redirect to a new splitapp page. Inside one of those generic tiles I have to show the entire splitapp view with some modifications. I know we can add multiple content inside a Tile content using vbox, but is it possible to add the entire splitapp? I tried it, but it displays nothing other than just increasing the height of the tile.

What i have tried is -

```
  <TileContent>
    <Vbox>
      <SplitApp id="idAppControl"></SplitApp>
     </Vbox>
  </TileContent>
```

This just increases the height of the tile but displays nothing.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: I have a splitApp and a home screen.In the home screen i have tiles on which if i click i will be redirected to the splitapp.Now my question is ,in the tiles only is it possible to show the splitapp

Comment: Would this not represent a misuse of the Tile? Conceptually Tiles serve as a navigation mechanism to the app. They are equipped to provide some very high-level summary info. I think when you break the purpose of a component you run into unnecessary challenges like the one above? My perspective - not sure why you would want to show an app on what is effectively a navigation to that app?!